# IComparer using Lambda Expression

Tags: c#-3.0

```
 class p {
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int Age { get; set; }
 };

 static List<p> ll = new List<p>
 {
     new p{Name="Jabc",Age=53},new p{Name="Mdef",Age=20},
     new p{Name="Exab",Age=45},new p{Name="G123",Age=19}
 };
 protected static void SortList()
 {
     IComparer<p> mycomp = (x, y) => x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);  <==(Line 1)
     ll.Sort((x, y) => x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name));<==(Line 2)
 }
```

Here the List.sort expects an `IComparer<p>` as parameter. And it works with the lambda 
as shown in Line 2.  But when I try to do as in Line 1, I get this error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to
>   type
>   System.Collections.Generic.IComparer'
>   because it is not a delegate type

I investigated this for quite some time but I still don't understand it.Maybe my understanding of IComparer is not quite good.Can somebody give me a hand ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you do `ll.Sort((x, y) => x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name));` it uses the overload for `Comparison<T>`, not `IComparer`. `Comparison<T>` is a delegate, so you can use a lambda expression for it.

`Comparison<p> mycomp = (x, y) => x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);` will work.

Comment: Where/how is Comparison<T> defined?

Comment: @duluca It's defined in the `System` namespace as `public delegate int Comparison<in T>(T x, T y)` (minus the `in` in versions prior to .net 4). It's documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: `CompareTo()` is a culture specific comparison. Something like `ll.sort((x, y) => String.CompareOrdinal(x.Name, y.Name))` may suit you better.

Comment: I like how I could lift the *exact* mycomp definition here to work in my scenario :)

Comment: @RyanKirkman How often do you want to compare two `Name`s according to the numeric value of the underlying UTF-16 code units? Normally, when you sort "names" you use an alphabet relevant in the context, and that is indeed culture-specific.

Answer (score 9):

There's an existing solution you might refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16839559/371531

This one uses Comparer<T>.Create introduced in .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: This is a great one :)

Answer (score 2):

IComparer is an interface, not a delegate.

You'll want to use the lambda expression on its .CompareTo(), not on the interface itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following simple class:

```
public static class ComparerUtilities
{
    class _Comparer<T> : Comparer<T>
    {
        Comparison<T> _comparison;

        public _Comparer(Comparison<T> comparison)
        {
            _comparison = comparison;
        }

        public override int Compare(T x, T y)
        {
            return _comparison(x, y);
        }
    }

    public static IComparer<T> FromComparison<T>(Comparison<T> comparison)
    {
        return new _Comparer<T>(comparison);
    }
}
```