# organize a list with files according to time stamp

Tags: c#, list, datetime, lambda

I have a list of strings that contains paths to files. I want to order this list according to the creation time of the files (first element should be the newest file)
I work with C#. I thought of using a lambda but so far I get stuck with this line. it recognizes that result as DateTime object, how can I get the name of the file itself. It feels like a simple problem but I am new to lambda expression.

```
nameList.Sort(x => File.GetCreationTime(x));
```

thanks,

Comment: So you want two things - you want to 1) sort the list according to creation timestamp, and then 2) convert the resulting list of paths to just the file names, is that correctly understood?

Comment: 1/ is correct and 2/ i just want that original list reordered that's all. the original strings...

Comment: You already have that. Try inspecting `nameList` after calling `Sort(...)`

Comment: i forgot the error message: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'IComparer<string>' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IComparer using Lambda Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893176/icomparer-using-lambda-expression)

Comment: Or `var fileList = new DirectoryInfo([Your Path]).EnumerateFiles().OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime);`, so you have more options.

Comment: @Jimi  your solution seems nice but i get the following error. 'IEnumerable<FileInfo>' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' and no accessible extension method 'OrderBy' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<FileInfo>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: You need `using System.Linq;`. -- When you have this kind of notifications, just put the caret inside the underlined keyword and press `ALT+ENTER`, VS will suggest the namespace / assembly / NuGet Package to add.

Comment: thank you so much; i adopt this solution!!

Comment: Well, if you find that this is a solution to a problem, then post an answer with a description that explains why this solves the problem. -- BTW, having a collection of `FileInfo` objects is quite good for data binding: you can handle different *situations* because you have a number of properties to act upon. -- Remember to call `Refresh()` before accessing a `FileInfo` object (to refresh the cache, so you don't try to access a file that has been modified / moved / deleted etc).

Comment: So duplicate of [Order (and enumerate) directory listing by file creation date?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10965165/3744182) then?

Answer (score 0):

Answer of Jimi is the easiest one:

```
var fileList = new DirectoryInfo([Your Path]).EnumerateFiles().OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime);
```

it's easy to work with fileinfo